# Passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, gcc-warning

I am getting warning:

> miniunz.c:342:25: Passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *'
>   discards qualifiers

in miniunz.c file of the [Zip Archive library](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive). Specifically:

```
const char* write_filename;
fopen(write_filename,"wb"); //// This work fine...........
makedir(write_filename);    //// This line shows warning....
```

How should this warning be removed so that both work fine?

Comment: Please try this `makedir((char*)write_filename);`. hope this will help you.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the definition of `makedir`: there is no reason I can see why it shouldn't be able to accept a `const char*` argument, so you should change it so that it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the `miniunz.c` file from [Zip Code](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive/blob/master/minizip/miniunz.c).

The function definition is as follows:

```
int makedir (newdir)
    char *newdir;
```

So by considering that,
There are two ways to do this.

```
  char* write_filename;

              fopen((char*)write_filename,"wb");
                 makedir(write_filename);
```

**OR**

```
  const char* write_filename;

              fopen(write_filename,"wb");
                 makedir((char*)write_filename);
```

Or Check your `makedir()` function.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You don't need to cast for `fopen`. Also, I would really recommend not casting `const` away from `char *`. If `makedir` modifies the string, and you pass literal string which is placed in read-only memory, you will get undefined behaviour. It is not portable code. Proper way would be to make non-const copy of string for the function that needs it.

Answer (score 3):

An improvement upon the original answer:

You have a function which takes an `NSString *` as a parameter.

First you need to convert it to a `const char` pointer with `const char *str = [string UTF8String];`

Next, you need to cast the `const char` as a `char`, calling

`makedir((char*)write_filename);`

In the line above, you're taking the `const char` value of `write_filename` and casting it as a `char *`and passing it into the `makedir` function which takes a `char *` as its argument:

`makedir(char * argName)`

Hope that's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter being passed to `makedir` is of type `char*` and not of type `const char*`.

The warning you're getting is warning you that passing a value with the `const` qualifier (in this case, `write`) to a parameter without it removes the `const` qualifier from the value. One way to avoid this warning is manually removing the `const` qualifier from `write_filename`, as below:

```c
char* write_filename;
fopen(write_filename,"wb");
makedir(write_filename);
```

However, I don't recommend this, because you may want to keep `write_filename` `const`. If you want to avoid this warning while keeping `write_filename` `const`, you can manually cast it to a normal `char*`, as below:

```c
const char* write_filename;
fopen(write_filename,"wb");
makedir((char*) write_filename);
```